# Does the BigQuery JS SDK support CORS?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, google-api-js-client

Is there support for CORS in the BigQuery client-side JavaScript SDK? Specifically, can a user make a request inside of my app that their gets data from BigQuery, without having to proxy the request to avoid CORS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The BigQuery API is a normal Google API, and Google APIs support CORS. If you use the full Google APIs JavaScript client, then this will be handled for you, and it will just work.

If for some reason you don't want to use the complete Google APIs JavaScript client, this page discusses how to do CORS manually, using just the auth portion of the library:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

But using the complete JavaScript library will be easier, so I recommend you do that.